# How to Identify the text over flow in RichEditableTextArea

Tags: apache-flex, textarea, flash-builder

I am working with `RichEditabletextArea`. I want to know whether the text fits that textarea or it over flows out of the `textarea`.
The below image will help you to understand the scenario.[image]

In the above screenshot the last word gets trimmed due to overflow of text beyond the textarea. How can i get a solution for this

Comment: Do you have to use RichEditableTextArea? With a normal textArea it is a lot easier to handle this problem

Comment: With normal textarea how it can be handled?? @GaryPerry

Comment: Yes, there are a few ways to handle it with a textArea, thanks to some properties that richEditableTextArea doesn't have.

Comment: Can u tell me how to handle this in textarea??/

Comment: Are you using flex 3 or flex 4?

Comment: Am using Flex 4.. @GaryPerry

Answer (score 0):

Try using a label with the max displayed lines attribute, this will truncate your text to the number of lines you can have, and then add a tooltip with the same text so that when you hover over the label the tooltip will appear with the whole text.

```
 <s:Label text="foo" maxDisplayedLines="3" toolTip="foo"/>
```

Hope this can work.

Comment: Oh, okay im sorry, i didnt really understsand the question, where do you get the text from? do the users wright it themselvs?

Comment: Okay, so why are you using a textArea? anyway if you want to use one then you will have to implement the component, and create a method that controls how many lines fit in your text Area, and truncate the text once it passes that number.

Comment: Nope. I have to implement that with textarea. Can u help me in that please.